# Array.Clear() vs Buffer.BlockCopy()

Tags: c#

### Background

> I have to clear fixed-length managed byte arrays (ex: `byte[4096]`) very frequently.

*My question is seeking an answer that applies to generic-usage, but for those who are wondering where this question stems from: I am currently optimizing my object pool of `byte[]`. I need to wipe it clean when it is returned to the pool.*

---

### My Question

> Between using the `Array.Clear()` method to clear the array or using
> `Buffer.BlockCopy()` method to overwrite the array with a blank one,
> which method will perform better?

---

### Sample Code

Using `Buffer.BlockCopy` to clear a byte array

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(blankArray, 0, array, 0, 4096);
```

**- VERSUS -**

Using `Array.Clear` to clear the byte array

```
Array.Clear(array, 0, 4096);
```

---

### My Research

```
public class Benchmark
{
    const int NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS = 10000000;
    const int SIZE = 4096;
    static byte[] _blank = new byte[SIZE];
    static byte[] _array = new byte[SIZE];

    public static int ArrayClear()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS; i++)
        {
            Array.Clear(_array, 0, SIZE);
        }

        return NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS;
    }

    public static int BlockCopy()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS; i++)
        {
            Buffer.BlockCopy(_blank, 0, _array, 0, SIZE);
        }

        return NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS;
    }
}
```

Code used to run the benchmark

```
public class Program
{
    static Func<int>[] labs =
    {
        Benchmark.BlockCopy,
        Benchmark.ArrayClear,
    };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < labs.Length; i++)
        {
            long counter = 0;
            int[] gcCounters = new int[]
            { 
                GC.CollectionCount(0), 
                GC.CollectionCount(1), 
                GC.CollectionCount(2) 
            };

            Console.WriteLine(labs[i].Method.Name + "()");
            Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew(); // start benchmark
            counter = labs[i].Invoke();
            stopwatch.Stop(); // end of benchmark

            DisplayResults(gcCounters, stopwatch, counter);
        }

        Console.Write("\nPress any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void DisplayResults(int[] gcCounters, Stopwatch stopwatch, long counter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Total elapsed time was {0:N2} seconds",
            (stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds / 1000)
        );
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Total garbage collection (generation 0) was {0} collections", 
            (GC.CollectionCount(0) - gcCounters[0]).ToString("N0")
        );
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Total garbage collection (generation 1) was {0:N0} collections", 
            (GC.CollectionCount(1) - gcCounters[1])
        );
        Console.WriteLine(
                "Total garbage collection (generation 2) was {0:N0} collections", 
                (GC.CollectionCount(2) - gcCounters[2])
            );
        if (counter > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                "Average processing time per iteration took {0:N2} microseconds", 
                ((double)stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds * 1000 / counter)
            );
        }
    }
}
```

#### The results

**BlockCopy() results**

```
 Total elapsed time was 3.22 seconds.
 Total garbage collection (generation 0) was 0 collections.
 Total garbage collection (generation 1) was 0 collections.
 Total garbage collection (generation 2) was 0 collections.
 Average processing time per iteration took 0.32 microseconds.
```

**ArrayClear() results**

```
 Total elapsed time was 0.90 seconds.
 Total garbage collection (generation 0) was 0 collections.
 Total garbage collection (generation 1) was 0 collections.
 Total garbage collection (generation 2) was 0 collections.
 Average processing time per iteration took 0.09 microseconds.
```

> It seems that `ArrayClear` is faster. I'm not sure if this means it performs better as well.

Comment: Have you measured the time with benchmarkdotnet or similar ?

Comment: For `Buffer.BlockCopy` you need _two_ arrays. That's an extra memory allocation, etc. for no gain. If `Array.Clear` doesn't run at the speed that you need (which is not terribly likely), you can use unsafe code and wipe the array using 64-bit writes. It doesn't get much faster than that.

Comment: @xxbbcc SIMD wipes or block wipes :)

Comment: @MarcGravell Or those. :)

Comment: You can also use `RtlZeroMemory`, although if you have a pre-allocated byte array (assuming that the size is _always_ the same and is only ever read), `Buffer.BlockCopy` would be your easiest choice - no need to import it and it's pretty fast. At the end, you should probably time it, as Marc suggested, if you're really down to this level of performance differences.

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: There is a simple typo in the benchmark, it accidentally reversed the names of the methods.  So it is actually Array.Clear() which is faster.  Which is intuitively obvious of course.  There is still something wonky with Buffer.BlockCopy(), it gets quite a bit faster when you pass the array as an argument.  Not entirely obvious why that is the case, but it doesn't matter all that much since you favor Array.Clear() anyway.

Comment: I was hoping this major edit would encourage people to undo the down votes, but people don't revisit questions... How do you resolve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your research has lead you to the right conclusion: `Array.Clear()` outperforms `Buffer.BlockCopy()` in this particular scenario.

## BenchmarkDotNet

To run benchmarks like this, use [BenchmarkDotNet](http://benchmarkdotnet.org). Your benchmark can be simplified and run using BenchmarkDotNet as follows:

```
using System;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;

namespace Experiments
{
    [MemoryDiagnoser]
    public class Test
    {
        const int SIZE = 4096;
        static byte[] _blank = new byte[SIZE];
        static byte[] _array = new byte[SIZE];

        [Benchmark]
        public void ArrayClear()
        {
            Array.Clear(_array, 0, SIZE);
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public void BlockCopy()
        {
            Buffer.BlockCopy(_blank, 0, _array, 0, SIZE);
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BenchmarkRunner.Run<Test>();
        }
    }
}
```

## Results

I ran this benchmark on .NET Framework under x86 and x64, and on .NET Core under x64. The following results show that in all experiments, `Array.Clear()` outperforms `Buffer.BlockCopy()`:

```
# Clr 4.0.30319.42000, 32bit LegacyJIT-v4.7.2053.0

     Method |        Mean |    StdDev | Allocated |
----------- |------------ |---------- |---------- |
 ArrayClear | 154.6503 ns | 0.0192 ns |       0 B |
  BlockCopy | 655.8208 ns | 0.0939 ns |       0 B |

# Clr 4.0.30319.42000, 64bit RyuJIT-v4.7.2053.0

     Method |        Mean |    StdDev | Allocated |
----------- |------------ |---------- |---------- |
 ArrayClear | 179.2065 ns | 0.0205 ns |       0 B |
  BlockCopy | 320.4117 ns | 0.0380 ns |       0 B |

# .NET Core 4.6.25211.01, 64bit RyuJIT

     Method |        Mean |    StdDev | Allocated |
----------- |------------ |---------- |---------- |
 ArrayClear | 107.5015 ns | 0.0145 ns |       0 B |
  BlockCopy | 221.3139 ns | 0.0449 ns |       0 B |
```